# maven variable inheritance and resolution

Tags: maven, inheritance

I have a multi parent project (child with grandparent pom).  The grandparent pom specifies a variable (happens to be the version) that gets overridden by the child.  How can I get that value to either be static or reference the "top" parent?

*realizing this may need clarification*

Let's say that our grandparent pom is

```xml
<groupId>group</groupId>
<artifactId>grandparent-pom</artifactId>
<version>1.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
<properties>
    <grandparent-pom-version>${version}</grandparent-pom-version>
</properties>
```

This puts the un-substituted variable in the installed pom file, so everything that inherits from it is substituting the local value.  One alternative is to look back at the parent `${parent.version}`, but this gets lost once we hit the third generation.

Comment: I had a similar need and ended up [using the `gmaven-plugin`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15962647/944849).