# Have maven list (transitively) inherited parent POMs?

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3

Is there an easy way to make maven list the parent POMs a POM inherits directly and indirectly?

I'm looking for something similar to

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

only "upstream" (i.e. for parent POMs inherited), not "downstream" (i.e. for dependencies on other libraries)...

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to print the version of our corporate parent POMs.  I used the GMaven plugin for this, as described in this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15962647/944849).    You could modify that code bit to print each parent POM.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a Maven command to do this. If you use Eclipse and the m2e plugin, then you can press <kbd>F3</kbd> inside of the `<parent>` element to visit the parent POM. Then rinse and repeat.

Comment: I use IntelliJ, and you can ctrl+click there, but I thought surely there must be a better way to do this...

Comment: Eclipse also has some views on the POM but they only show the dependencies, not the way up.