# With maven, how can I get the absolute path to where my root pom is?

Tags: maven

I need to get the absolute path to a subdirectory located just below where my root pom is.
For example the pom is at:
`c:\somepath\pom.xml`
I need to get the absolute path to:
`c:\somepath\myIncludes\`
I need this while building in a pom with a path like one these:
`c:\somepath\subdir1\pom.xml`
`c:\somepath\subdir1\evendeeperdir\pom.xml`

To try to stave off comments about how this is a dumb thing to need, I need this because:

- The C++ code that gets built by the pom needs a path to includes.
- There are multiple C++ projects with different relative paths ( so even though relative paths can work, it is too tedious and error prone to use multiple relative paths )
- The project is mostly java (so I want to build it all with maven)
- The whole thing is giant and legacy, so I cannot make sweeping changes in the structure.

Comment: Make it a property in the pom.xml

Comment: Try with ${project.basedir} [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html) there are some information about pom

Comment: That almost works, but, I just realized I need a the directory a parent pom is in.  So that I can set the path once from it and use it in child poms that are at different depths in the directory structure ( I will modify the question )

Comment: @Solx Well then simply use `${project.basedir}/../myIncludes`. It is messy but will work.

Comment: I think you should take a look at https://github.com/maven-nar/nar-maven-plugin

Comment: @Tunaki I believe I found that ${project.basedir} varies by which pom you are 'running' so if you are using ${project.basedir} in the parent pom but running maven from a child pom, then ${project.basedir} gets the child poms path.

Comment: @Solx That is correct, but you should probably not run Maven from a child pom to begin with ;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once upon a time I needed to do something similar, but I needed a version. Perhaps you can adapt the procedure in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15962647/944849) to determine a root directory.

Comment: This looks like it might do it, but I cannot figure out what other attributes rootPom has.  I am really hoping one is its path.

Comment: rootPom is just a Maven POM with all the properties a POM has in the [Maven API](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/maven-core/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/maven/Maven.html). As I read the question, I think `rootPom.basedir` is what you're looking for.

Comment: I used your idea to work out a solution.  I used gmaven (groovy) to get the path to the pom is being built.  Then I used goovy to extract the part of the path I needed.  The solution is a real mess, but will give me the path.

Comment: But I will try your suggestion for 'rootPom.basedir' as soon as I get a chance, if it works it will be much cleaner.  I am going to mark this an the answer because it pointed me to the means to do what I needed, and may help someone else in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Declare a property in root pom as
`<properties><rootdirectory>${project.basedir}\myIncludes</rootdirectory> </properties>`

For child pom's, override the the value of rootdirectory as
`<properties> <rootdirectory>${project.parent.basedir}\myIncludes</rootdirectory> </properties>`

Comment: Interesting, what if I need it in a pom under that child, would I need to do something like:
<rootdirectory>${project.parent.parent.basedir}\whatever</rootdirectory>

Comment: @Solx thats right. It was the cleanest way I could find that worked.

Answer (score 0):

Create an env variable by adding a property to the maven profile settings`

```
<profile>
        <id>local-properties</id>
        <properties>
            <SOME_PATH>yourPath</SOME_PATH>
        </properties>
</profile>
```

Comment: This will be use by various people with varying absolute paths.  I am looking for a method that automatically determines the path.

Comment: @Solx have you found this solution?

Comment: The solution I ended up using was to put a file with a specific name in the top directory and then running a groovy script to walk up directories to find it.