# Add suffix in maven release plugin

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

I would like to add a `TEST` suffix when building with the Maven release plugin. The idea that if the user which builds the artifact ticks a checkbox, then a `TEST` version is build.

So the POM contains a version like `1.2.3-SNAPSHOT` and I would like to build `1.2.3-TEST`. The Maven release plugin allows you to set the target version, but I do not know how I should reference the original version (or parts thereof) for the new version, like

`${oldVersionWithoutSnapshot}-TEST$`.

Any ideas how to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try the [Build Helper Maven Plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/index.html).

The `parse-version` goal parses the version to get the component parts, and `regex-property` does replacements.

I've also used the [GMaven](https://github.com/groovy/gmaven) plugin before to set properties, but not for as specific a use case as yours. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15962647/944849) gives the idea.

Comment: Thank you, I can indeed reconstruct the original version with Snapshot from the three version parts.