# Maven pom version inheritance

Tags: spring-boot, maven, maven-3

I have 3 projects Parent,Child,SubChild.

Project  Parent pom is as follows:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<groupId>mu.parent</groupId>
<artifactId>parent-system</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
```

....

Project Child pom is defined below and its **Parent** is defined follows:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>mu.parent</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent-system</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>
    
    <groupId>mu.dummy.child</groupId>
    <artifactId>child-backend</artifactId>
    <name>child-backend</name>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <modules>
        <module>subChild-app</module>
  
    </modules>


...
```

Now subChild pom is as follows and the child is defined as parent for subChild :

```
 <parent>
            <groupId>mu.dummy.child</groupId>
           <artifactId>child-backend</artifactId>
          <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
 <groupId>mu.dummy.subchild</groupId>
    <artifactId>subchild-backend</artifactId>
    <name>subchild-backend</name>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.project.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>project</artifactId>
       <version></version> --version of parent-system???
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

Is it possible to get version of parent-system(1.0) in subchild-backend please without hardcoding it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CI-friendly versions and write `${revision}` for the versions, setting this property in the main pom (from which you build everything).

You need to use the flatten Maven plugin, though, to get proper POMs in the repository.

Answer (score 0):

I asked a similar question a while back and determined that tthe `groovy-maven-plugin` works for this. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15962647/944849).

Comment: Hi i tried it but how do you access  project.properties.setProperty('root.pom.version', 
                                                pom.version);  in your child pom? this is not working  <version>${root.pom.version}</version>

Comment: Glad you tried it. Looking again, this may not work where you want to use it. Maven resolves dependencies pretty early in the process, before executing plugins. I am curious as to why you need to specify a grandparent POM as a dependency though?

Comment: basically the org.project.test is a common-project and its parent is parent-system.so its version should be align with the version of its parent

Comment: You might have better luck with something like the `maven-enforcer-plugin` then. It has a [list of rules](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/index.html) you may apply, including some that manage versions.